# Alternatives to Google Sites for a personal web site?

Tags: web-hosting, google-sites

I'd like to find a hosting solution for my personal, fairly low-traffic, web site. I think Google Sites would suit me perfectly, but I've heard horror stories about Google's algorithms shutting down all your accounts on a whim, with no right of appeal, so I'm naturally worried, because I don't want to lose my Gmail.

**Edit** *I'm talking about cases like [this one](http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-04-14/how-i-lost-access-my-google-account-today):*

> I tried contacting somebody at Google support ("Surely they should
>   have a support department, right?" Nope, wrong!)

*(The victim managed to regain access to his Gmail account when his case went "viral", but he never got an explanation as to why he had been locked out in the first place)*

Are there good, preferably free, alternatives to Google Sites and what are their PROs and CONs? One requirement is that I should be able to point the DNS (*foobar.com*) to it.

Comment: Well you can use Webs.com, blogger, or WordPress.com and cname to them.

Comment: @Anagio Blogger is also part of Google's empire, isn't it?

Comment: Well if you're hosting questionable content then you should just host it yourself so you don't have to worry about your account being shutdown. If you plan to host content which Google would close your site for. I'm sure the same will happen at any free host.

Comment: @Anagio I don't have any plans to host questionable content. Are you saying Google doesn't get any false positives? From what I've heard (on Hacker News, mostly), the most common reason for a shutdown is the algorithms (NLP?) deciding that you encouraged the users to click on the ads, or some other ToS violation. No human ever reviews the case, and you get locked out of all your accounts.

Comment: False positives for a website? Ok so now you're talking about AdSense invalid clicks not website content. That's completely different if Google feels someone was clicking on Ads they'll close your AdSense account. And with hundreds of millions of dollars they are pretty damn smart at catching people doing it. Yes they have very clearly outlined guides for placing Ads and what you can and cannot place near the ads. Yes humans review your AdSense cases. I know for a fact that even when an AdSense account is closed and reviewed they can be re-instated.

Comment: No, I mean "false positive" in the most traditional sense: The algorithms decide that you violated the ToS somehow, when you haven't. You can't appeal, and you get locked out of all your Google accounts.

Comment: Yes you can `appeal` you can actually email and call Google and speak with humans. They are pretty friendly when no sketchy activity was going on they'll see that an open your account back up. I'm not going to start pasting email conversations with proof accounts are opened again. I hope you'd trust what i'm saying. If you are so worried about your account closing from what you read on hacker news I get the feeling you have some questionable ideas when it comes to AdSense and your website. Again if you're worried about your accounts closing host your own website yourself and don't use AdSense.

Comment: @Anagio Well, I don't have any personal experience with Google's customer service, but I can say that *by far* the prevailing opinion on HN is that Google has terrible to non-existent customer service. You can search for "site:ycombinator.com google customer service" to see for yourself.

Comment: If you're not hosting bad content and following their rules for AdSense you have nothing to be afraid of. Right?

Comment: @Anagio Here's an example: http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-04-14/how-i-lost-access-my-google-account-today

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 I just read that post. Note that the victim posted the following as resolution http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-04-14/how-i-lost-access-my-google-account-today#comment-1850 His account was re-enabled in exactly 24 hours. And when asked why it happened, he responded http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-04-14/how-i-lost-access-my-google-account-today#comment-1860

Comment: @FeralOink His case went "viral" - that's how he got his account back. If you need to reach the top of HN to get your gmail back, that's a sad state of affairs.

Comment: Google has support departments for all of their services

Comment: All our comments aside, if we are using Google's services, and servers they have every right to close any account for any and no reason at all without explanation. If you don't like that setup your own domain your own mail servers and use another ad network.

Comment: @Anagio do you work for Google or something? I asked a question, and your reaction was to accuse me of cheating and other wrong-doing. Seriously?

Comment: Well if you have done nothing you can call them. No I do not work for Google. I would say the same if you said you got banned from PayPal, Clickbank, CJ.com or any other service. If you followed their rules plead your case and hope for the best. They have support and they re-open cases which have not gone viral

Comment: @Anagio *I would say the same if you said you got banned from PayPal, Clickbank, CJ.com or any other service.* So, you are just assuming that the customer is always wrong? Good luck with that attitude.

Comment: No I would tell you to contact their support is what I would say. Email or call them i'd say the same exact thing

Comment: Try aBuckAnApp.com, it's free and it's pretty reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You could host it through your dropbox! [Site44](http://www.site44.com) or [droppages](http://droppages.com) are two good options for this. Super simple and easy to maintain and upgrade. Handy to be able through a simple text editor on the iPhone to update your website by a simple dropbox upload.

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order:

- Blogger - http://www.blogger.com/
- Posterous Spaces - https://posterous.com/
- Tumbler - https://www.tumblr.com/
- Twitter + TwitLonger - https://twitter.com/ + http://www.twitlonger.com/
- Wordpress.com - http://wordpress.com/
- Wordpress.org + pretty much every web host - https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+hosting
- Typepad - http://www.typepad.com/
- Blog.com - http://blog.com/

A recent roundup of free options (some of which I've mentioned): http://sixrevisions.com/tools/top-free-online-blogging/

As for the DNS issue, many domain name registration services provide domain name forwarding. I use Namesecure for that: https://www.namesecure.com/

Personally, hosting is so cheap these days, I'd recommend finding the most affordable hosting account you can and hosting your own Wordpress site. It's easy, flexible, and gives you the full power of that tool and any other you might choose to run, as well as some free FTP space and other perks.